# MongoDB replica set slow query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have set up MongoDB replica set with 6 servers, everything is working fine, data is replicated, no problem there.

When i connect from node.js directly to primary server insert query execution time is less than 20 milliseconds, but when i list all servers in connection string ([documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#the-url-connection-format)) execution time of query increases abnormally, ranging from 1.5 seconds to 11 seconds.

I use native mongodb package with latest version (https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)

MongoDB version is 3.0.10.

Example of connection string:

```
mongodb://s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6/my_database?replicaSet=repl
```

I have tried various options, like setting write concern to 0  (even if it's set in replica set configuration to 1) and journal to true, but nothing works

Even if i use only 2 servers in connection string execution time still increases.

Replica set configuration:

```
{
"_id" : "repl",
"version" : 7,
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 0,
        "host" : "mongo1:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 2,
        "tags" : {},
        "slaveDelay" : 0,
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "host" : "mongo2:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {},
        "slaveDelay" : 0,
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "host" : "mongo3:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {},
        "slaveDelay" : 0,
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "host" : "mongo4:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {},
        "slaveDelay" : 0,
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 4,
        "host" : "mongo5:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 1,
        "tags" : {},
        "slaveDelay" : 0,
        "votes" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : 5,
        "host" : "mongo6:27017",
        "arbiterOnly" : false,
        "buildIndexes" : true,
        "hidden" : false,
        "priority" : 0.5,
        "tags" : {},
        "slaveDelay" : 0,
        "votes" : 1
    }
],
"settings" : {
    "chainingAllowed" : true,
    "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
    "getLastErrorModes" : { },
    "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
        "w" : 1,
        "wtimeout" : 0
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Any chance you found a solution to this? I am experiencing very similar behaviour